# I want to have my sub menu directly under my 'Services' page. Also, to have a border around the sub menus so as not to blend in pages

Tags: wordpress, elementor, submenu, border-layout

[image]

This is from another site and I want to change the bg color but first, I want to have my sub menu pages directly underneath my 'Services' tab and a border. I'm more of a beginner, so any step-by-step help would be great. Using Wordpress and free version of Elementor. Can't see my site as it's a default, 'Under Maintenance' image I have there now.

Tried to copy and paste 'stuff' from Google and YouTube. Not results that have helped.